# How can I reverse the direction of bones in my armature?

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

I spent a lot of time building up my armature for my dragon model and then, after I was all done and started to refine it, I realized that the bones from the pelvis out to the end of the tail were **pointing the wrong way** - they need to have their heads pointing the other direction:

[image: Armature with bones pointing in the wrong direction]

I don't want to have to delete these bones and start over.

Is there an easy way to **switch the direction of the tail bones**?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Switch Direction of Bones

Thankfully Blender has a simple command that will reverse the direction of selected bones called "Switch Direction". You can access this two different ways:

- Select rig > <kbd>Tab</kbd> > select bones > *Specials* menu (<kbd>W</kbd>) > *Switch Direction*
- Select rig > <kbd>Tab</kbd> > select bones > *3D View* Header > *Armature* menu > *Switch Direction*

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say its hard to find, its in the **Armature** menu.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I had been looking for something to "Reverse direction" ("Switch" never occurred to me) and I was also looking for a Bones menu item in Armature, i.e. Armature -> Bones -> Reverse Direction.

Comment: For Blender 2.8x the shortcut is now Alt + F

Answer (score 8):

Blender has a function to switch the direction of Bones, however its worth noting that there is also the ability to select a bone chain in one step:

- Enter *Edit Mode* <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Select a bone on either end of the chain you want to flip <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click <kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the other bone in the chain.
  *(this selects bones in between, matching similar behavior in mesh editmode)*
- *Armature* menu *> Switch Direction* (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>)