# A quick way to know the names of the relationships there are between bones without trying to guess

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I spent a lot of time building up the armature of Piero (I'm following the `Piero training course by CG Cookie`) and then, after I was all done and started to refine it, I realized that the bones from the pelvis out to the end of the tail were pointing the wrong way - they need to have their heads pointing the other direction. Since I don't want to have to delete these bones and start over,I switched the direction of the tail bones,according with this post :

[How can I reverse the direction of bones in my armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/how-can-i-reverse-the-direction-of-bones-in-my-armature)

Now the problem is that all the relationships that were there before are gone and I have to create them again. To do this,I've got the final rigged version of Piero and I tried to understand what are the relationships between the switched bones. For example,the bone called `DEF_tail.006` is connected to a lot of other bones and for me it's hard to understand what they are. Check the pic below :

[image: bones relationships mess]

So,the question is : Is there a quick way to know the names of the parents that there are between bones without trying to guess by hiding them one by one ? thanks.

Comment: You can see the entire parenting hierarchy in the outliner window (in the top right of your screenshot). Is that what you mean?

Comment: No,because though the outliner window I don't see what are the connections between the bones,where they start and where they finish. I'm talking about the dashed lines contained inside the black circle that you see on this pic : https://postimg.org/image/58ci4nud3/

Comment: Enable names or switch from octahedral to stick?

Comment: it helps,but not so much when there are a lot of superimposed polygons.